# Imageview doesn't set center

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to display my imageview center of the screen. I used below xml code, but my image displayed only near by margin. I referred developer site, it given android:ScaleType. But i used scaletype also. My image not set center of the scrren.
listview.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="5px"                
                android:paddingTop="5px"
                android:paddingLeft="5px">


   <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
              android:scaleType="fitCenter">
                </ImageView>
<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="20px"
          android:textStyle="bold"

            android:textColor="#0099CC">
                </TextView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your relative layout's `layout_width` to `fill_parent`. That may be  the problem..

Comment: why don't you use **android:layout_centerInParent** attribute instead of **android:scaleType**

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="5px"                
            android:paddingTop="5px"
            android:paddingLeft="5px">



<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="20px"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:layout_alignTop="@id/ImageView01"

        android:textColor="#0099CC">
            </TextView>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
          android:layout_gravity="center">
            </ImageView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try using Graphical layout to drag and align correctly in center of layout